# Blocking incoming connections on tun0 using UFW

Tags: vpn, firewall, ufw

I am running 16.04 using PIA as my VPN.

I have configured the UFW with the following commands.

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing

sudo ufw default deny incoming

sudo ufw deny in on tun0 to any

sudo ufw allow out on tun0 to any

sudo ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 1198 proto udp

sudo ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 53

sudo ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 443

sudo ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 1723

sudo ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 2000

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1080

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
```

The problem being is that even though I am denying incoming on tun0 I am still able to see multiple open ports on the VPN address namely 22,53,80,110,443,500,1723 and 8888 using NMAP port scan.

I am even able to connect to the SSH server on the box using my given VPN address.

What have I missed?

Any ideas we be appreciated.

Comment: Which computer is connected to the VPN, and from where are you trying to connect to it? For instance, you are allowing all connections to ports 22,1080,80 for the local subnet 192.168.0.1/24.

Comment: My main machine (I work on) is a Win10 box and goes through Squid Proxy which is also installed on the Ubuntu box (for browsing only on the Win10 Box using Squid). I have tested the ports remotely using pentest-tools online as well as the local NMAP software. I am yet to try it from outside my own network. I was thinking of testing by tethering my Laptop to the mobile and seeing if I get the same results. Thanks